# How to resume enumerate list with different names?

Tags: enumerate

I would like to have something like this.

- Comment 1. blablabla
- Response 1. blablabla
- Comment 2. blablabla
- Response 2. blablabla

I need the bullets to be Comment 1., Response 1., etc.

My attempt was this.

```
\documentclass[onecolumn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcounter{count}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={Comment \arabic*.}]
    \item \textit{blablabla.}\\~\\
    \begin{enumerate}[label={Response \arabic*.}]
        \item blablabla
        \setcounter{count}{\theenumi}
    \end{enumerate}

    \item \textit{blablabla.}\\~\\
    \begin{enumerate}[label={Response \arabic*.}]
        \setcounter{enumi}{\thecount}
        \item blablabla
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

which gives me this error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   {
l.10             \setcounter{count}{\theenumi}
```

Comment: `\theenumi` is not a number but has a dot most likely. This does not work. And `enumitem` provides means for resuming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick way, using the `start=...` option of the inner list. I'll try to update with a better way.

The main issue is, that `\theenumi` isn't just outputting 1 or 2 but `1.` and `2.`, i.e. there's a dot at the end. This can't go into a `\setcounter{...}{...}` command, since counter values must be integers, not alphanumerical values.

```
\documentclass[onecolumn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={Comment \arabic*.}]
\item \textit{blablabla.}%\\~\\
  \begin{enumerate}[label={Response \arabic*.}]
  \item blablabla
  \end{enumerate}

\item \textit{blablabla.}%\\~\\
  \begin{enumerate}[label={Response \arabic*.},start={\value{enumi}}]
    \item blablabla
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**Update** with special lists:

Define special lists, say `comments` and `responses`, both being of depth `1` only and set the start of `responses` always to be of the current value of `commentsi`, which is counter defined by `\newlist` then. Deeper nesting would define `commentsii`, `commentsiii` and `commentsiv`.

```
\documentclass[onecolumn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{comments}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[comments,1]{label={Comment \arabic*.}}

\newlist{responses}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[responses,1]{label={Response \arabic*.}, start={\value{commentsi}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{comments}
\item \textit{blablabla.}
  \begin{responses}
  \item blablabla
  \end{responses}
\item \textit{blablabla.}
  \begin{responses}
  \item blablabla
  \end{responses}
  \end{comments}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. If I want the bullets to be in one `\begin{enumerate} ... \end{enumerate}` environment, can I still do that? I mean without the responses being indented.

Comment: @Jika: Yes, the local settings are just as usual specified with `[...]`

Comment: @Jika: Add `leftmargin=0pt` to the setlist options for `responses`. This will remove the indentation of `responses`